# How can l manipulate 2 select boxes dynamically

Tags: javascript

How can l manipulate 2 select boxes dynamically, were if i select value 1 on select box A then select box B will show values Dog,Cow,Cat. If Value 2 selected then select box B shows bus,car,bike

```
<select id='A'>
<option value='1'>Value 1</option>
<option value='2'>Value 2</option>
</select>
```

if value 1 is selected then
    
    Dog
    Cow
    Cat
    
if value 2 is selected then
    
    Bus
    Car
    Bike

Comment: You're probably going to want to use JavaScript for this, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple javascript solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="updateselect('A', 'B');">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function updateselect(this_id, other_id){
            if (document.getElementById(this_id).value == "1"){
            document.getElementById(other_id).innerHTML="<option>Dog<\/option><option>Cow<\/option><option>Cat<\/option>";
            }
            else if (document.getElementById(this_id).value == "2"){
            document.getElementById(other_id).innerHTML="<option>Bus<\/option><option>Car<\/option><option>Bike<\/option>";
            }
        }
    </script>
    <noscript>JAVASCRIPT IS NOT ENABLED FOR THIS PAGE</noscript>
    <select id='A' onchange="updateselect('A', 'B');">
        <option value='1'>Value 1</option>
        <option value='2'>Value 2</option>
    </select>
    <select id='B'></select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you all, @elliospizzaman i have tried it but select box B is not populating the option values, its always blank

Comment: Did you use my exact script? It worked for me. I tested it in Safari on an online HTML editor.

Comment: i have used the exact script and am using IE version 9.0.8112

Comment: See if you have any javascript problems on other pages. Try reading this article: http://www.sevenforums.com/browsers-mail/151469-ie9-problem-javascript.html